# How to set bootstrap-vue text color inside template

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I want to use something like that

```
<span text-variant = 'danger'>text</span>
```

or

```
<b-col cols = 12 text-variant = 'danger'> text </b-col>
```

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: ```<b-col>``` stand for column and span is another HTML tag. So they are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `class="text-danger"` in both of your examples.